# Stained Glass Sidelight Window

Tags: windows, subpanel, exterior, replacement

I have one sidelight window which has frosted glass inside and clear outside.   I have researched and determined it is impossible to find a new window with stained glass.  Can the outside glass be removed and stained glass window film be applied inside for the stained glass look?  Will this work?  Is there a problem with pulling the outside glass out?  Are there other options to obtaining a stained glass look?

Comment: I'd just apply the stained-glass-image window film to the inside surface of the existing glass. It'll look fine from outside, and judging by my own it won't look bad from inside. Depends on how critical you are about the illusion... but realistically, you're going to mostly stop seeing it after a month or two.

Comment: It's far from 'impossible' to get new stained glass, either real or convincing fake  - https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/276631/37954

Comment: It'd also help if you provided pics (in and out) of what you have.  I wonder if you have some kind of custom IGU with frosted glass on one side.  Even though it's most common nowadays to apply a frosting (spray or film) to plain glass.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a larger city (or if you're lucky, a smaller town with a stained glass craftsperson), I'm sure it will be possible to find a stained glass artisan who would be able to make a custom-designed window that would fit your space, with a design to your liking.  It won't be cheap, but would do exactly what you're wanting.